# Sort by nested field ignored when sorting by multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have nested field in the the document. When I perform `sort("nestedField.id", "fieldA")` first argument is being ignored, when I perform `sort("fieldB", "fieldA")` it works as expected. Performing sort on single nested field `sort("nestedField.id")` works as expected.
Why this could be the case?

Comment: could you share your queries?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch_dsl library for Python so I don't have native Elastic search queries. Maybe it is an issue with a library...